# ASP MVC use of Remote Validation throw error of entity type is not part of the model for current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm using a ASP MVC with Entity Framework and I do not have control over the structure of the Database and so having the database-first, I made the disabled the migration with `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;`. Inside the database is a table named `tblUser` which is part of my EF, everything is fine with the database-first and EF but my problem occurs when I tried to extend the `tblUser` and add the MVC Remote, it actually works fine inside the View but it throws an error when I reach the `saveChanges()` part. So here the code for my `tblUser` EF:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


    public partial class tblUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]  
        public virtual string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then my custom extended `CreateUserModel` derived from the `tblUser`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public partial class CreateUserModel : tblUser
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Admin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        [Remote("IsEmployeeNumberAvailable", "User", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Admin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameAlreadyExistError")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Admin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "WhiteSpaceNotAllowedError")]
        [Editable(true)]

        public override string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    }
}
```

No need to include my code of the `IsEmployeeNumberAvailable` since it's working fine in my View. The my code of the `Create` function inside my `UserController`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserModel user, FormCollection collection)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Step #1 - Save the User info
        user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        user.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        _dbCtx.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
        _dbCtx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and finally here is the error thrown:

```
The entity type CreateUserModel is not part of the model for the current context.
```

Now I know that `CreateUserModel` is not part of my EF mapping diagram and I know it's failing because of that but seriously I only extended the `tblUser` model because of the Create action as I do not want it to block my Edit action. I did not add anything new, I mean no new field, I simply extended the employee number for validation purpose only. Oh I also added the `DbSet` inside the `DbContext` with the following:

```
public DbSet<CreateUserModel> CreateUserModel { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `tblUser` entity, copy the properties over and add that entity to the context:

```
var tblUser = new tblUser
{
    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
    FirstName = user.FirstName,
    LastName = user.LastName,
    // etc.
}
_dbCtx.Users.Add(tblUser);
_dbCtx.SaveChanges();
```

(or use a tool like AutoMapper to support the property copying).

EF really only understands the classes that are "registered" as entities and no derived classes, even not if the derived class doesn't add or modify any property and is completely empty.

The `DbSet<CreateUserModel>` (where you apparently try to register the derived class as entity) has no effect because you are not using Code-First but Database-First in which case the model is not infered from code but from the EDMX diagram. In EDMX `CreateUserModel` is still unknown - and I believe it would be a REALLY HUGE violation of separation of concerns principle to declare a (or even every) *view model* as a *persistence model*. Saving a few lines of dull property copying is not worth the resulting architectural mess.

Comment: Thanks for answer, though my `tblUser` does exist in my EF but the `CreateUserModel` does not. I will remove the `DbSet` as you said since yes it doesn't belong there. I think that I have to cast from `CreateUserModel` to a `tblUser` so that EF knows about it

Comment: @ghiscoding: Ah, casting, good idea. Let me know if that works. I'm not sure if EF will be happy then or if it checks the actual runtime type of the object (which wouldn't change with casting).

Comment: Thx for reply... The actual casting didn't work directly but passing the properties from one to the other did work, that is on a new object of `tblUser`. I got help from a co-worker :) I'll +1 your answer but I'll write my answer tomorrow... Thx again

Comment: I just realized that you had the proper answer, haha I just misread it..good job ;)